# How to solve CPLEX with tuple as a string and int input?

Tags: arrays, string, tuples

```
    int nbProducts = ...;

    int nbCustomers= ...;

    int nbPeriod = ...;
```

//input data from excel as int in order to satisfy

```
 tuple PCP1{

   string ProdID;

   string CustID;

   string PeriodId;

   }

tuple PCP2 {

    string ProdID;   

}

tuple PCP3{   

    string CustID;   

}

tuple PCP4{   

    string PeriodID;   

}

tuple PCP5{

    string ProdID;

    string SupID;

    string PeriodId;

}

tuple PCP6 {

    string ProdID; 

}

tuple PCP7{   

   string SupID;   

}

tuple PCP8{   

   string PeriodID;   

}

 setof(PCP1) PCP_list1 = ...;  

 setof(PCP5) PCP_list5 = ...;  

 setof(PCP2) PCP_list2 = {<f> | <f,j,v> in PCP_list1};

 setof(PCP3) PCP_list3 = {<j> | <f,j,v> in PCP_list1}; 

 setof(PCP4) PCP_list4 = {<v> | <f,j,v> in PCP_list1}; 

setof(PCP6) PCP_list6 = {<f> | <f,j,v> in PCP_list5}; 

setof(PCP7) PCP_list7 = {<j> | <f,j,v> in PCP_list5};

setof(PCP8) PCP_list8 = {<v> | <f,j,v> in PCP_list5};
```

float Demands[1..nbProducts*nbCustomers*nbPeriod] = ...;

float Demand[ p in 1..nbProducts,s in 1..nbCustomers, c in 1..nbPeriod] = Demands[c+nbPeriod*(s-1)+nbCustomers*nbPeriod*(p-1)];

```
dvar boolean x[PCP_list2][PCP_list3];

dvar boolean x_sup[PCP_list6][PCP_list7][PCP_list8];

dvar boolean x_cus[PCP_list2][PCP_list3][PCP_list4];

 minimize sum(i in PCP_list2, j in PCP_list3 ) x[i][j];

subject to


   { forall( i in PCP_list6, j in PCP_list7, k in PCP_list8)
       x_sup[i][j][k] <= 1000; 

   forall(i in PCP_list2, j in PCP_list3, k in PCP_list4)
       x_cus[i][j][k] == Demand[i][j][k];

  forall( i in PCP_list2, k in PCP_list4)
       sum( c in PCP_list3 ) x_cus[i][c][k] <=  100; 
}
```

//I have problem with constraint in the second constraint
Second constraint cannot be read directly I have been trying to solve but cannot think of function to resolve.

Comment: Please format code as code and not as normal text. Furthermore, the description of your problem is not sufficient. You don't mention your programming language, you don't mention when / under what circumstances your problem occurs, and so on. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I tried to add as a code but for my device I do have no idea how. Nevertheless, I appreciate your recommendation.